# Angular 6: create my own database while using a database from public api?

Tags: html, database, angular, api

I am working on an angular 6 project and I need to know if I can get a database from a public api but also from an in-memory database?
Which means for example show movies from a public api but also be able to add my own movies so that it shoes on my website.
I just want to create a basic database that when I reload the page, the database disappears.

If yes, how can i do so without using backend?

Thanks 
Ava

Answer (score 1):

I really don't know if I understood your question properly but I thought of sharing some info which might be useful for you.

You can use the browser's [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to temporarily save your data. And if you want your database to disappear when you reload, you can manipulate with logic to clear your local storage from the code. Like, onInit of the component, clear local storage.

Use [json-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-server) if you want a small data base. It actually serves as a real database

Comment: Ok that i understood but i need to use both a public api and my own database for this project, the thing is that I dont know how to show both on my page... like how can i show both my data and the api’s data ??

Answer (score 0):

There are some public api sites, where you can fetch data, and even mock post and put requests too. For instance [json placeholder](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

To be able to extend that data, you need the specific implementation to always extend the result with your "in-memory database". So for instance in a component, you store your data in a property, and in the http communication listeners do something like this:

```
this.http.get('placeholder-api',{someBodyData}).subscribe(
  response => {
    results = [...response, ...myInMemoryDbArray]
  }
);
```

If you post the specific function you want to implement and has difficulties with, can help you more.

Comment: The thing is that I need to use a specific api to show data but be able to do a basic CRUD to add, edit data. here is my code : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cakhuj ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use firebase. For tutorial https://www.tutorialspoint.com/firebase/ .

Comment: You don need a backend. You can easily use in angular.

Comment: I mean im using nodejs as backend i cant use another one